# How to define in Matlab the function $f(x,y)=\left ( xy,x-y^2,3x-2y \right )$

Tags: matlab

I need to define the function $f(x,y)=\left ( xy,x-y^2,3x-2y \right )$, how can I do this in Matlab?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possibility:

---

function [a,b,c] = fun1(x,y)

a=x*y;

b=x-y.^2;

c = 3*x-2*y;

---

Save this as "fun1.m" (in your work directory). Now you can for example calculate

fun1(3,2)

Answer (score 8):

How about

f = @(x,y) [x*y, x - y^2, 3*x - 2*y] ;

Comment: It may be better to use .* operators if any matrix operations are extected to be computed elementwise.